# I225 Ethernet Controller - SPI Flash

Tags: spi, ethernet, intel

I'm designing a motherboard with Tiger Lake UP3 CPU, and I want to use Intel I225 Ethernet controller for the LAN ports.

I225 reference design includes an SPI flash. I couldn't find what is the purpose of this SPI flash or if we can give up on it.

Note: in the SPI flash design notes, it's written that a 16Mb SPI Flash is required for supporting Option-ROM (PXE code), and 8Mb SPI Flash can be used when Option-Rom is not needed.

I can understand for example in the 16MB case why the SPI is useful. but I still don't know why it's useful in the 8mb case.

Comment: Does that chip have a public datasheet? If not then you have to ask for the manufacturer about it. If I had to guess it is used for at least storing the MAC address.